# custom ko binding for jquery data tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have used jquery dataTable in knockout.js.In that i am generating data rows from function with remove link.It will remove row form table as well form observable array.The remove link works once and remove the row from table but when i try to remove another one they do not remove it.

Here you can check http://jsfiddle.net/zongweil/PLUKv/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

/* Custom binding */
ko.bindingHandlers.dataTable = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var binding = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        // If the binding is an object with an options field,
        // initialise the dataTable with those options. 
        if (binding.options) {
            $(element).dataTable(binding.options);
        }
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var binding = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        // If the binding isn't an object, turn it into one. 
        if (!binding.data) {
            binding = {
                data: valueAccessor()
            };
        }

        // Clear table
        $(element).dataTable().fnClearTable();

        // Rebuild table from data source specified in binding
        $(element).dataTable().fnAddData(binding.data());
    }
};


/* Object code */
function GroupMember(id, name, isGroupLeader) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = id;
    self.name = name;
    self.isGroupLeader = ko.observable(isGroupLeader);

    self.link = ko.computed(function () {
        return "/#user/" + self.id;
    });

    self.nameWithLink = ko.computed(function () {
        return '<a href="' + self.link() + '">' + self.name + '</a>';
    });

    self.actions = ko.computed(function () {
        return '<a class="btn btn-danger" data-bind="click: function() {removeMember(' + self.id + ')}">' + '<i class="icon-minus-sign"></i>' + '</a>';
    });
}

/* View model */
var groupViewModel = {
    groupMembers: ko.observableArray([
    new GroupMember("1", "Abe", true),
    new GroupMember("2", "Bob", false),
    new GroupMember("3", "Bill", false)])
};

groupViewModel.membersTable = ko.computed(function () {
    var self = this;

    var final_array = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < self.groupMembers().length; i++) {
        var row_array = new Array();
        row_array[0] = self.groupMembers()[i].nameWithLink();
        row_array[1] = self.groupMembers()[i].actions();
        final_array.push(row_array);
    }

    return final_array;
}, groupViewModel);

groupViewModel.removeMember = function (id) {
    var self = this;

    self.groupMembers.remove(function (groupMember) {
        return groupMember.id == id;
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(groupViewModel);
```

});

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of your earlier question: [knouckout js and jquery data table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37230475/knouckout-js-and-jquery-data-table)? Note that you can improve your original question by editing it, which would place it in the queue for reopening.

Comment: Here is a [plugin](http://jmvtrinidad.github.io/knockout-datagrid/) that you can use for manipulating table.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `fnClearTable` in your custom binding's `update` function, you clear a part of your DOM behind knockout's back.

You then add new DOM elements by calling `fnAddData`.

Your buttons work using the `click` binding. For the `click` binding to work, knockout has to `applyBindings`.

If you want to keep using both the `dataTable` and a `click` binding to work with the DOM, you'll have to manually apply bindings every time you make a change. In your `init` method, let knockout know you're taking care of descendant bindings:

```
return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
```

In your `update` method, apply bindings by hand:

```
ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(viewModel, element);
```

This makes sure your `click` bindings will work again.

Here's your example with this code added: http://jsfiddle.net/5t15rhyq/